# android and parsing documents in xml

Tags: java, android, xml

To my app is sent data in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><response><status>FAIL</status><time>2012-12-11 22:35</time></response>
```

I can read this data by:

```
String si;
while(is.available()>0){
    si+=(char)is.read();

}
```

But using Document builder:

```
Document doc=db.parse(sock.getInputStream());
```

Hangs my application in this place.

Can somebody explain me this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by hangs?

Comment: ain't going no step more in code (no errors or exceptions)[after this line is only logging.]. Do I need to set something before in db to work?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the socket input stream never signals end of file and so the parse method just hangs waiting for the next character.  I suggest using your example loop to collect the XML and then pass the string to the parse method by wrapping it in a ByteArrayInputStream or StringBufferInputStream.

Comment: can I set timeout or something else to prevent this behaviour ?

Comment: The sock.setSoTimeout method controls the read timeout.  I would start with sock.setSoTimeout(100).  That will set the timeout to one hundred milliseconds.  You might have to try some different values to find the right balance between performance and not timing out prematurely.